# Kalman filter estimation

Tags: fitting

Does anyone have any examples of the estimation of Kalman filters in Mathematica? I am new to these filters and struggling to compose the likelihood function. Some examples would be really helpful. The specific case I am working with involves three state variables and constant coefficient matrices whose elements are linear functions of the underlying variables, and the variance term in the state equation is a function of past realisations of the state variable. The specific example is the Cox-Ingersoll-Ross multifactor interest rate model given in equations 59 -76 here:http://www.bankofcanada.ca/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/wp01-15a.pdf.

Comment: Seen [KalmanFilter](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/KalmanFilter.html)?

Comment: and [KalmanEstimator](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KalmanEstimator.html) and [ConstructAKalmanFilterForAStochasticSystem](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/ConstructAKalmanFilterForAStochasticSystem.html) and [StructuralModelsAndTheKalmanFilter in time series application](http://reference.wolfram.com/applications/timeseries/UsersGuideToTimeSeries/StructuralModelsAndTheKalmanFilter/index.en.html)

Comment: Thanks. The time series reference looks particularly helpful.

Comment: @Nasser - could you perhaps work this up into an answer with a couple of examples? And Luke, welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you find the site useful.